# Iterating over a Dataset TF 2.0 with for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

This problem is about how to iterate over a TF Dataset given that `make_initializable_iterator()` is deprecated.

I read a data set with the function below:

```
def read_dataset_new(filename, target='delay'):
    ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)
    ds = ds.map(lambda buf: parse(buf, target=target))
    ds = ds.batch(1)
    return ds
```

Then I want to iterate over the data set. I have been using:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#make_initializable_iterator

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    data_set = tfr_utils.read_dataset_new(self.tf_rcrds_fl_nm)
    itrtr = data_set.make_initializable_iterator()
    sess.run(itrtr.initializer)
    features, label = itrtr.get_next()
    features_keys = features.keys()
...
```

But "Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use for ... in dataset:...."

Apart from the deprecation warning, my code works as expected.

Given the deprecation warning, though, I am now trying this:

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    data_set = tfr_utils.read_dataset_new(self.tf_rcrds_fl_nm)
    for features, label in data_set:
        features_keys = features.keys()
        ...
```

But that does not work. I get:

```
self = <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x12f2e57d0>
fn = <function BaseSession._do_run.<locals>._run_fn at 0x12f270440>
args = ({}, [<tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TF_Output; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'TF_Output *' at 0x12f3f75a0> >], [], None, None)
message = 'Resource AnonymousIterator/AnonymousIterator0/N10tensorflow4data16IteratorResourceE does not exist.\n\t [[node Iterat...tNext_1 (defined at /demo-routenet/tests/unit/test_tfrecord_utils.py:376) ]]'
m = <re.Match object; span=(102, 130), match='[[{{node IteratorGetNext_1}}'>
```

The code samples I have been able to find all explicitly create an iterator, which is apparently not what one is supposed to do. I can't find an example of what one is supposed to do though.

I suspect that something has not been initialised. So, I also tried:

```
sess.run(data_set)
```

But that didn't work either (nor do I have any reason to suppose it should have, but just so you all know what I tried).

So, how does one use a Dataset in a for loop as the deprecation comment suggests please?

Comment: Having read the latest guide on TF 2.0, I am now understanding that eager execution is now intended to be the default mode. From: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2

"TensorFlow 1.X requires users to manually stitch together an abstract syntax tree (the graph) by making tf.* API calls. It then requires users to manually compile the abstract syntax tree by passing a set of output tensors and input tensors to a session.run() call. TensorFlow 2.0 executes eagerly (like Python normally does) and in 2.0, graphs and sessions should feel like implementation details."

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you want to get at your output.
If you want to get the values of the dataset output you should execute eagerly.
Example:

```
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

def read_dataset_new(filename, target='delay'):
    ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)
    ds = ds.map(lambda buf: parse(buf, target=target))
    ds = ds.batch(1)
    return ds
# This should return your key values for each example.
for features, labels in read_dataset_new(self.tf_rcrds_fl_nm):
    features_keys = features.keys()
# This should return your tensor values if they supposed to be numeric.
for features, labels in read_dataset_new(self.tf_rcrds_fl_nm):
    features_array = numpy.array(features)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a version of my code that works as you suggest above here https://github.com/Data-Science-Projects/demo-routenet/blob/master/tests/unit/test_omnet_tfrecord_utils.py#L398. 

That code works because I am calling tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution(). That does not represent the code idiom for when I am delaying execution of the graph for use in a session later.

I shall work on this and see if there is a version of the code than can work in a session.

Comment: Version 2 of the API has this comment for __iter__:

Creates an Iterator for enumerating the elements of this dataset.

The returned iterator implements the Python iterator protocol and therefore **can only be used in eager mode**.